# .NET AMQP SeviceBus request/response

Tags: .net, azure, microservices, azureservicebus, amqp

I'm using in Azure Service Bus in one of my projects.
I need to implement Request/Response pattern between on-premise docker container and AKS container on Azure cloud.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-request-response.

1. What is the best way to implement this pattern in .NET?
2. I can't find any updated example for this.
3. There is any limitation or problems with this pattern?

Comment: The link you mentioned is about AMQP protocol support in Azure Service Bus for communicating with that. I’m not sure how it would help in your scenario where you want to communicate between on-prem Docker and AKS.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thank you for your quick response.
That what I'm trying to understand, What is the best way to communicate between the services through ServiceBus without exporting API.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Service Bus is a messaging service. AMQP is the protocol it implements. When you work with [Service Bus SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) you work with entities such as queues, topic, and subscriptions. The entities are used to exchange messages. Messaging is to break the coupling between parties. For example, [Request/Reply pattern](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReply.html) that allows breaking away from the synchronous Request/Response pattern. I would recommend the following:

1. Understand messaging principles
2. Review wherever you really need Request/Response or Request/Reply
3. Review [Service Bus documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/service-bus-messaging/)